# Could not understand the note with Promise.prototype.then() in MDN Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm learning to convert my Node.js code style from callback to promise which seems to be the tendency and it has many advantages. To prevent the misunderstanding of the important points and benefits of the promise, I'm reading
[document on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) . I can understand **Examples** in this page, but I am not clear with the **note** that at the beginning of the document, it had mentioned :

> Note: ... If the first argument is omitted or provided a non-function,
> the new Promise that is created simply adopts the fulfillment state of
> the Promise that then is called on (if it becomes fulfilled). If the
> second argument is omitted or provided a non-function, the new Promise that
> is created simply adopts the rejection state of the Promise that then is called
> on (if it becomes rejected).

Sorry in advance if this is trivial.
Hope for the explanation with examples, thanks.

Comment: @Joe Clay,@torazaburo,really appreciate both of your answers , two ways to explain same thing just made me more clear about what I asked . Both aspect are all detailed and awesome to me , it's difficult to decide which to accept , sorry that I just accept torazaburo's which discuss more mechanism behind. But Joe's is valuable , too, thank you guys again .

Comment: No problem, I think torazaburo's explanation was clearer :) Glad I could help to some degree, anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers provide good explanations, but it might be easier to express this using the concept of **skipping over**.

> If and when the promise **fulfills**, then the **first** argument to `then` is invoked (as long as it is a function); if and when the promise **rejects**, then the **second** argument to `then` is invoked (as long as it is there and is a function). In other cases, the `.then` is just skipped over.

Purists would object that it is incorrect to say the `.then` is "skipped over", and that what is really happening is that the `.then` creates a new promise which is equivalent to (or assumes the state of) the original promise. That's technically correct, but informally it's easier to talk and think about the `.then` getting "skipped".

Examples:

```
function log(v) { console.log("value", v); }
function err(e) { console.log("error", e); }

Promise.resolve(1).then(null, err).then(log);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ "SKIPPED" (onFulfilled is null)

Promise.reject(1).then(log).catch(err);
                  ^^^^^^^^^        "SKIPPED" (onRejected is not given)
```

For completeness, the corresponding behavior for `catch` is:

> If and when the promise rejects, then the argument to `catch` is invoked (as long as it is a function). In other cases, the `.catch` is just skipped over.

```
Promise.resolve(1).catch(err).then(log);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^      "SKIPPED" (promise did not reject)
```

If you think about it carefully, you will see that this all means that `.then(null, handler)` is **exactly** equivalent in every way to `.catch(handler)`. So `catch` can be thought of as a kind of convenience routine.

But what's the point of allowing, but then ignoring, non-function handlers? Shouldn't they throw a `TypeError` or something instead? Actually, this is a "feature" which can be used as follows:

```
promise.then(isWednesday && wednesdayHandler)
```

If it's Wednesday, then this will evaluate to `wednesdayHandler` and we can do some special Wednesday processing. It it's not Wednesday, then this will evaluate to `false`, which is obviously not a function, so the whole `then` clause will be "skipped".

Comment: What the way to handle non-function handlers could make use of really amazed me ! I didn't learn about this when survey on many other information .Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

***EDIT:*** Updated to better match the spec - see [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promisereaction-records).

The `.then` method calls one of two functions, depending on whether or not the Promise it's attached to has *fulfilled* or *rejected*. It then returns a new Promise based on the result of that call. This allows you to run different logic depending on whether or not a Promise was successful, and makes it possible to chain Promises together easily.

If you decide not to pass in one of those functions, however, it uses sensible defaults - which is what the note you posted is alluding to. It's probably a lot easier to demonstrate than to describe, though!

---

If you leave out the `onRejected` callback, like so:

```
myPromise.then(function (value) {
    console.log("success!");
});
```

The result is the same as doing this:

```
myPromise.then(function (value) {
    console.log("success!");
}, function (reason) {
    throw reason;
});
```

---

If you leave out the `onFulfilled` callback, like so:

```
myPromise.then(null, function (reason) {
    console.log("fail!");
});
```

The result is the same as:

```
myPromise.then(function (value) {
    return value; // the same as returning Promise.resolve(value)
}, function (reason) {
    console.log("fail!");
});
```

---

If you leave both out... it's basically pointless, but still:

```
myPromise.then();
```

This is effectively the same thing as:

```
myPromise.then(function (value) {
    return value;
}, function (reason) {
    throw reason;
});
```

Which is in turn, basically just:

```
myPromise
```

Comment: @torazaburo: I updated my answer to use the correct terminology, thanks for the correction! I'm not 100% sure about your last comment though - leaving the `onFulfilled` callback out definitely works as expected (just tested it in my console), and the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen) goes out of its way to state what behavior should happen if it's not a callable value. This isn't to say I think it's a good idea to use it that way, though!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have too much to add to this that the other answers don't already--just that I came to this question in the process of writing my own question about this, at which point SO miraculously suggested this one as a possible duplicate (when it did not come up in my previous search attempts).

Anyways the current documentation on MDN on the [parameters to Promise.prototype.then](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#parameters) have changed a bit since the OP and I think are still confusing, if not even moreso than before, so I thought I would add a follow-up answer concerning the current documentation which reads:

> `onFulfilled` Optional
>
> A `Function` called if the `Promise` is fulfilled. This function has one argument, the `fulfillment` `value`. If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an "Identity" function (it returns the received argument).

What's confusing about this wording is it's not totally clear what is the antecedent of "received argument".  Without already being familiar with the details of the Promises spec, one could read this as the "identity" function returning the argument received by the `then()` call.  I.e. that something like this:

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("value"));
let chained = promise.then("new value");
```

is equivalent to this:

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("value"));
let chained = promise.then(() => "new_value");
```

so that the value resolved from `chained` is `"new_value"`.

When in fact, "received value" refers to the resolved value of the original promise that `.then()` was chained from, i.e.:

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("value"));
let chained = promise.then(() => "value");
```

So writing `promise.then("not_a_callable")` completely ignores `"not a callable"` and is resolved to the value that fulfilled the original `promise`, whatever it happens to have been.

Personally, I think this confusing behavior, but it is what it is.